# Ruby algorithm help using cron jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm determined to get this algorithm (if you want to call it that) figured out over the weekend and I think I'll need the help of cron jobs or maybe [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork).

**Here's my logic:**

When adding a book, it needs to be stuck in a "queue line" or "queue status" and will only be "published" at the top of the week. At the top of the week, if no book has been "queued", add a new "published" book & make the form available again (the form will get hidden once a book has been queued to publish next). When I say top of the week, I mean that a book must be published every 7 days, going from the date the user's account was created.

To give some background, I'm creating an app where users are encouraged to read one book per week over the course of 2013 (yeah this thing has to launch by Monday!). They are able to add a book that they're going to read the next week and change the status of that book to 'read' once they read it. If they don't change the status to 'read' within 7 days of adding it, it automatically gets moved down the line and displays as 'unread' and the new blank book gets added (like what I explained above).

The whole adding of books and changing the status to read/unread is already complete. I'm just looking for help setting up the 7 day incremental book adding and "queue line".

**Some insight into my code:**

I have a `books` controller & model that `belongs_to` a user. My user model `has_many` books.

I'm adding and displaying the users' books through the user `show` view.

I'm sure there are things that I'm leaving out that will help better explain my environment, so just ask me :) Thanks!

Comment: Please improve your question by posting [properly formatted](http://superuser.com/editing-help) code. In addition, please post any actual error message you received, and what steps you've taken so far to research or resolve your issue.

Comment: I hardy posted any code. Didn't know it wasn't "properly formatted". I'm looking for more of a higher level answer than a straight "here's the code to do this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a chron job for this.

What I would do is add a status to each book of read/unread. And then write a method in the model that checks on page load and modifies the view or controller data for display.

Rails/Ruby has some nice date/time helpers where you can say date1 <= 7.days.ago.

Is there any reason why this approach won't work?

Comment: Yes, I already have a status for read/unread. Not sure if I can specifically say 7 days ago, because what if a user adds a book in the middle of the week? And I think I still need a way to add a book if one isn't "queued up", which would be done through a chron job right?

Comment: Rails has a created_at and modified_at field on each book. You could use those. You also could create your own if those don't work for you.

Comment: Okay so realizing that this is the wrong syntax, I could do something like this couldn't I? ```<% if @user.books.created_at > @user.books.count * 7 %>
 <!--show the queued book-->
 <% else %>
 <!--show form-->
<% end %>``` Which basically says if the book was created before the other books, show it as queued. But then no that's not right, cause if I wanted to do that all I'd have to do would be call ```latest```. Argh!

Comment: So then I guess what I really need it to say is "if a book was published this week, queue the next one". No?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly how it is supposed to work. Can you add something like:

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly how it is supposed to work. Essentially, you should be able to put some view logic that basically says, "if the last book was added more than 7 days ago, display form for adding new book". Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm after. And also, if the last book was added more than 7 days ago and there isn't a book "queued", add a blank one. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can all of what I just said above be done directly in the view, w/o helper methods? I realize that's probably not "the Rails way" but it will do for now if I can do it.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to me all that can be done in the view. You might want to set a variable in the controller to compare against in the view to keep your view a little cleaner.